# How to apply identation on a bulleted list of texts in html?

Tags: html

I have a text as follows :

• To access your FSA information from 07/01/2014 – 06/30/2015 please click the following link and follow the “New User” instructions. www.connectyourcare.com

The issue here is that the next line positions itself to the extreme left, attached to the body. I want it to start from just beneath the 'To' word in the first line and so on and so forth for the third line.

Here is the small piece of code :

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" bgcolor="rgb(209,225,255)">
<tr>
<td>
• To access your FSA information from 07/01/2014 – 06/30/2015 please click the following link and follow the “New User” instructions. <a href="http://www.connectyourcare.com/">www.connectyourcare.com</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you dont use a list?

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    To access your FSA information from 07/01/2014 – 06/30/2015 please click the following link and follow the “New User” instructions. <a href="http://www.connectyourcare.com/">www.connectyourcare.com</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yes, I have done that too, but the client has already coded the web using a predefined css. If i change it to unordered list I will have to make chages to those files as well.

Comment: For lists, its easier to use a `<ul>` and `<li>` instead of `<table>`. Even if you have to edit css files for the list, it will pay of to invest the time now. I _strongly_ recommend to use semantic correct html.

Comment: Sure, but for now is there any way to get through this with tr and td only?

Comment: Not as far as I know.. Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend using list for this. But if you have to do it with table then this is something you might try adding a td which holds just the bullet and another td which holds the content, like this:

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" width="100%" bgcolor="rgb(209,225,255)">
<tr>
<td>• </td>
<td>To access your FSA information from 07/01/2014 – 06/30/2015 please click the following link and follow the “New User” instructions. <a href="http://www.connectyourcare.com/">www.connectyourcare.com</a>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: yes, i just tried that, took a table inside the td tag as well, now working. thanks anyways :)